# How to make HtmlSelect Control with OnChange event to trigger C# code behind function

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-select, code-behind

How should I make "Html Select Control" with OnChange event to trigger C# code behind function
like ASP.NET **SelectedIndexChanged** of the DropDownList Control

For example
**Front end**

```
<select runat="server" id="xx" onserverchange="xx_ServerChange">
 <option>A</option>
 <option>B</option>
 <option>C</option>
</select>
```

**Back End**

```
protected void xx_ServerChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

PS:
1.Not like this [Select server changed
event](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0080__HTML-Controls/Selectserverchangedevent.htm)
,because it has to make another event button.
2.Don't use asp:DropDownList
3.Please don't use any redirect methods like Ajax or JQuery etc...

Comment: You can change the xx_ServerChange method as web method and call from front end using jQuery AJAX.

Comment: sorry ,it isn't useful for me ,thanks

Comment: What is the problem with Point 1 in you question? Seems like the correct solution.

Comment: @SehaxX I hope I can direct to use ChangedEvent to call c# function without redirect it like using JQuery  or AJAX etc...

Comment: As far as I know, you can use `onchange` event for `select` elements (not generated from `DropDownList`) but requires a `WebMethod` or `WebService` to return desired content, since HTML server controls have limited choices to do postback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a great way to handle my problems, showing my ideas as following code

Front End

```
  <select id="StartDate"  onserverchange="StartDate_ServerChange" runat="server">
  </select>
```

Back End

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
   ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
   this.StartDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", cs.GetPostBackEventReference(this.StartDate, this.StartDate.ID));
}
protected void StartDate_ServerChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

> PS: two references
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112(v=vs.110).aspx
>   https://blog.csdn.net/lovegonghui/article/details/51942241

Comment: I got the same issue and I used this method and its working. I have an asp.net web app. When one select onchange occures now whole page is post backed eventhough I put the two Select controls inside an update panel. Why update panel is not working?

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage please try to use a different ID for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to submit the form for the change to be registered:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select runat="server" id="xx" onchange="myForm.submit()" onserverchange="xx_ServerChange">
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
     <option>C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right, you need to use another control to trigger the code behind. Just add the button and access the state of the *select*

```
    <select runat="server" id="xx">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = xx.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

Comment: Not like this Select server changed event ,because it has to make another event button

Comment: You need the event to be trigger only directly by the user and the button should only change the value without triggering the event?

Comment: sorry I don't know what do you mean ,do you have any example ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax call in xx_ServerChange function from JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'PageName.aspx/functionName()',
    data: '{ }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        // Do something interesting here.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thnx Willie Cheng

Comment: Please look at this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help),it'll be help you to know about how to use StackOverflow